# How to setup my dual monitors

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, resolution

I have a nvidia video card and twin monitors. I tried using the nvidia_config and I had many problems especially after installing system updates. 
I have given up using the nvidia_congig  tool.

In order to get into my system last time because it would not boot into graphics mode i had to delete xorg.conf in /etc/X11 which enabled my computer to boot as I would expect it to.

Although my first screen is detected correctly my 2nd monitor is not and I do not seem to be able to set it up. Can I edit a config file somewhere that will fix this problem.

I am using 
2 identical monitors (AOC Intl 21inch) They both have a recommended resolution of 1920x1080 (16:9)

The output from `xrandr` is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3280 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
DVI-I-1 connected 1360x768+1920+11 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0*    59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384       119.9    119.6  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384       120.0  
   400x300       144.4  
   320x240       120.1  
DVI-I-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try reinstalling you nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia
```

Reboot afterwards to activate the new drivers.

I hope this helps.